# How to load a excel file from firebase storage in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, web-frontend

I have stored excel file into firebase storage in react.  I can create a download url but that will generate a download link of that file. But I want to show the excel data on webpage from firebase storage. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no natove way to display Excel files in html. You would need to download the file with javascript, read it with your code and convert it to html and css to display the data.

Alternatively you could convert the Excel to a convas, image or PDF and display that (if it doesn't need to be changed).

The third way would be to use some libraries that would at least make some of the above easier.